# Merge two objects in TTCN-3

Tags: ttcn

I have a lot of different templates defined in my TTCN-3 code. For simplicity let's focus on the example below:

```
type record Action {
    charstring name,
    charstring param optional,
    charstring state optional
}

template Action actionTemplate(param := *, state := *) {
    name := "Template",
    param := param,
    state := state
}

var Action actOne := {"Name", omit, "OK"};
template Action actTwo := actionTemplate(state := "NOT OK");
```

Is there a possibility to iterate over the actTwo fields, check if there is a value set and update the corresponding field in actOne? I'd like to do this in a generic way, because I don't always know the exact structure of template's subfields.

Is there a possibility to iterate over template fields like iterate over e.g. dict in Python where we have keys and corresponding values?

Answer (score 2):

You may apply the [TTCN-3 extension Advanced Parameterization](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_es/202700_202799/202784/01.05.01_60/es_202784v010501p.pdf) and implement a generic function that checks the template fields and may assign values to the variable.

In order to get more ideas please share your question with the TTCN-3 linkedIn group or [in the forum](http://www.ttcn-3.org/index.php/forum/index).

Comment: At this point I decided to write a plugin (shared lib) in C++ for TTCN-3, which takes an object and a template, iterate over the template and update object fields. I'll check if it's possible to do the same with your solution.